# jQuery - Using unique id for index function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I `remove` the item from the `wishlist` after it has been added using unique `id` for each item? The current code removes the item using a numeric index `i`, but I want to run the `on.change` function below by calling a unique identifier ex: `id="dog"` instead of `id="1", 2, 3`, etc.

Variable:

```
for (var i = 0; i < wish.items.length; i++)
```

Function in question:

```
  (function() {
    var currentIndex = i;
    $("#my-wish-remove" + currentIndex).on("change", function() {
      $(this)
        .closest("li")
        .hide(400);
      setTimeout(function() {
        wish.items[currentIndex].stock = "";
        update_product(wish.items[currentIndex]);
        $(".my-wish-add").eq(wish.items[currentIndex].id - 1).prop("checked", false);
        removeFromWish(wish.items[currentIndex].id);
      }, 400);
    });
  })();
```

```js
// Wish Function
var wish = {
  items: []
};
var update_product = function(product) {};
$(function() {
  //Add to wish
  var addToWish = function(product, qty) {
    qty = qty || 1;
    var wish = getWish();
    var indexOfId = wish.items.findIndex(x => x.id == product.id);
    if (indexOfId === -1) {
      wish.items.push({
        id: product.id,
        img: product.img,
        name: product.name,
      });
      $parent = $("#" + product.id).closest(".items__wish");
      $parent
        .find(".wish-icon")
        .addClass("active")
        .attr("data-prefix", "fas");
    } else {
      wish.items[indexOfId].qty++;
      wish.items[indexOfId].stock = Number(product.stock);
    }
    //Update popup wish
    updateWish(wish);
  };

  //Remove from wish on id
  var removeFromWish = function(id) {
    var wish = getWish();
    var wishIndex = wish.items.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
    wish.items.splice(wishIndex, 1);
    $parent = $("#" + id).closest(".items__wish");
    $parent
      .find(".wish-icon")
      .first()
      .removeClass("active")
      .attr("data-prefix", "far");
    //Update popup wish
    updateWish(wish);
  };

  var getProductValues = function(element) {
    var productId = $(element)
      .closest(".items__wish")
      .find(".item__tile")
      .attr("id");
    var productImg = $(element)
      .closest(".items__wish")
      .find(".item__img")
      .attr("src");
    var productName = $(element)
      .closest(".items__wish")
      .find(".item__title")
      .html();
    return {
      id: productId,
      img: productImg,
      name: productName,
    };
  };

  $(".my-wish-add").on("change", function() {
    var product = getProductValues(this);
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      addToWish({
        id: product.id,
        img: product.img,
        name: product.name,
      });
    } else {
      removeFromWish(product.id);
    }
  });

  //Update wish html to reflect changes
  var updateWish = function(wish) {
    //Add to shopping wish dropdown
    $(".wishlist__items").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < wish.items.length; i++) {
      $(".wishlist__items").append(
        "<li>" +
        '<div class="my-wish-item">' +
        "<img src='" +
        wish.items[i].img +
        "' />" +
        '<div class="wish-main">' +
        '<div class="wish-name">' +
        wish.items[i].name +
        "</div>" +
        '<div class="my-wish-remove-container">' +
        '<input type="checkbox" id="my-wish-remove' +
        i +
        '" class="my-wish-remove" aria-hidden="true">' +
        "<i class='fas fa-heart'></i>" +
        "</div>"
      );

      (function() {
        var currentIndex = i;
        $("#my-wish-remove" + currentIndex).on("change", function() {
          $(this)
            .closest("li")
            .hide(400);
          setTimeout(function() {
            wish.items[currentIndex].stock = "";
            update_product(wish.items[currentIndex]);
            $(".my-wish-add").eq(wish.items[currentIndex].id - 1).prop("checked", false);
            removeFromWish(wish.items[currentIndex].id);
          }, 400);
        });
      })();
    }
  };
  //Get Wish
  var getWish = function() {
    var myWish = wish;
    return myWish;
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Pro";
  font-weight: 900;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
}

.wishlist__list {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.wishlist__items li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="wishlist">
  <div class="wishlist__list">
    <ul class="wishlist__items">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='products'>
  <div class="items__wish">
    <div id='1' class='item__title item__tile'>Product 1</div>
    <img class="item__img" src="https://www.iconasys.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/360-Product-Photography-White-Background-Acrylic-Riser-08.jpg">
    <label class="wish-btn">
    <input type="checkbox" name="wish-check" class='my-wish-add'><i class="wish-icon far fa-heart"></i></input></label>
  </div>
  <div class="items__wish">
    <div id='2' class='item__title item__tile'>Product 2</div>
    <img class="item__img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQoqpSgkG4AQDQOe33jI1NiW3GW2JSB-_v36aREsVyFQH55JFOJ">
    <label class="wish-btn">
    <input type="checkbox" name="wish-check" class='my-wish-add'><i class="wish-icon far fa-heart"></i></input></label>
```

Comment: You can pass `data-itemid=YOUR-ITEM-ID` attribute in the checkbox so that `on change` event you can pass that itemid to the whish list item as an attribute and then whlie removing can compare if that particular id has been selected rather than index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the IDs with strings and did a small change to uncheck the items in the wish list,

```
$("#"+wish.items[currentIndex].id).parent().find($("label > input")).prop("checked", false);
```

and added a function that constantly shows the items in the `wish` variable.
Check the code below:

```js
    // Wish Function
    var wish = {
        items: []
    };
    var update_product = function(product) {};
    $(function() {
        //Add to wish
        var addToWish = function(product, qty) {

            qty = qty || 1;
            var wish = getWish();
            var indexOfId = wish.items.findIndex(x => x.id == product.id);
            if (indexOfId === -1) {
                wish.items.push({
                    id: product.id,
                    img: product.img,
                    name: product.name,
                });
                $parent = $("#" + product.id).closest(".items__wish");
                $parent
                    .find(".wish-icon")
                    .addClass("active")
                    .attr("data-prefix", "fas");
            } else {
                wish.items[indexOfId].qty++;
                wish.items[indexOfId].stock = Number(product.stock);
            }
            //Update popup wish
            updateWish(wish);
        };

        //Remove from wish on id
        var removeFromWish = function(id) {
            var wish = getWish();
            var wishIndex = wish.items.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
            wish.items.splice(wishIndex, 1);
            $parent = $("#" + id).closest(".items__wish");
            $parent
                .find(".wish-icon")
                .first()
                .removeClass("active")
                .attr("data-prefix", "far");
            //Update popup wish
            updateWish(wish);
        };

        var getProductValues = function(element) {
            var productId = $(element)
                .closest(".items__wish")
                .find(".item__tile")
                .attr("id");
            var productImg = $(element)
                .closest(".items__wish")
                .find(".item__img")
                .attr("src");
            var productName = $(element)
                .closest(".items__wish")
                .find(".item__title")
                .html();
            return {
                id: productId,
                img: productImg,
                name: productName,
            };
        };

        $(".my-wish-add").on("change", function() {
            var product = getProductValues(this);
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                addToWish({
                    id: product.id,
                    img: product.img,
                    name: product.name,
                });
            } else {
                removeFromWish(product.id);
            }
        });

        //Update wish html to reflect changes
        var updateWish = function(wish) {
            //Add to shopping wish dropdown
            $(".wishlist__items").html("");

            for (var i = 0; i < wish.items.length; i++) {
                $(".wishlist__items").append(
                    "<li>" +
                    '<div class="my-wish-item">' +
                    "<img src='" +
                    wish.items[i].img +
                    "' />" +
                    '<div class="wish-main">' +
                    '<div class="wish-name">' +
                    wish.items[i].name +
                    "</div>" +
                    '<div class="my-wish-remove-container">' +
                    '<input type="checkbox" id="my-wish-remove' +
                    i +
                    '" class="my-wish-remove" aria-hidden="true">' +
                    "<i class='fas fa-heart'></i>" +
                    "</div>"
                );

                (function() {
                    var currentIndex = i;
                    $("#my-wish-remove" + currentIndex).on("change", function() {
                        $(this)
                            .closest("li")
                            .hide(400);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            wish.items[currentIndex].stock = "";
                            update_product(wish.items[currentIndex]);
                            $("#"+wish.items[currentIndex].id).parent().find($("label > input")).prop("checked", false);
                            removeFromWish(wish.items[currentIndex].id);
                        }, 400);
                    });
                })();
            }
        };
        //Get Wish
        var getWish = function() {
            var myWish = wish;
            return myWish;
        };
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        if(wish.items.length > 0) {
            $("#wish_items").html(wish.items.map(function (elem) {
                return elem.id;
            }).join(", "));
        } else $("#wish_items").html('');
    },200);
```

```css
    body {
        font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Pro";
        font-weight: 900;
    }

    img {
        width: 50px;
    }

    .wishlist__list {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    }

    .wishlist__items li {
        list-style: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="wishlist">
    <div class="wishlist__list">
        <ul class="wishlist__items">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='products'>
    <div class="items__wish">
        <div id='headphones' class='item__title item__tile'>Product 1</div>
        <img class="item__img" src="https://www.iconasys.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/360-Product-Photography-White-Background-Acrylic-Riser-08.jpg">
        <label class="wish-btn">
            <input type="checkbox" name="wish-check" class='my-wish-add'><i class="wish-icon far fa-heart"></i></input></label>
    </div>
    <div class="items__wish">
        <div id='backpack' class='item__title item__tile'>Product 2</div>
        <img class="item__img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQoqpSgkG4AQDQOe33jI1NiW3GW2JSB-_v36aREsVyFQH55JFOJ">
        <label class="wish-btn">
            <input type="checkbox" name="wish-check" class='my-wish-add'><i class="wish-icon far fa-heart"></i></input></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div>Wish items: <span id="wish_items"></span></div>
```